# Calculating probabilities for $W~F(8,4)$ using a table.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The question is to find $P(0.198\le W\le 8.98)$. In the back of the book is a table where we can find values for these. So looking at the table, with $r_1=8$ and $r_2=4$, I found that $P(W\le 8.98)=.975$. Now, however, the only three values for these degrees of freedom given by the table are $6.04, 8.98$, and $14.8$. So I wasn't really sure how to find $P(W\le .198)$.

This was a homework problem I was assigned awhile back and the solution was to first find that $1/.198=5.05$. It says to then use $r_1=4$ and $r_2=8$ to get that $P(W\ge .198)=.975$.

Can someone explain this more generally? I'm assuming that when we start looking at $1/w$ we have to switch $r_1$ and $r_2$ and so that's why they did that. What's the reason for the inequality in the probability calculation switching directions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a fact that in general if $W\sim F(m,n)$ then $W^{-1}\sim F(n,m)$. To see this note that since $W\sim F(m,n)$ it follows that (in distribution)
$$
W=\frac{Y/m}{Z/n}
$$
where $Y\sim \chi^2_{(m)}$ and $Z\sim \chi^2_{(n)}$ and $Y$ and $Z$ are independent. In particular
$$
W^{-1}=\frac{Z/n}{Y/m}
$$ 
so that by definition $W^{-1}\sim F(n,m)$.

Now we return to your particular example. Suppose $W\sim F(8,4)$ so $W^{-1}\sim F(4,8)$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
P(0.198\leq W\leq 8.98)&=P(W\geq 0.198)-P(W\geq 8.98)\\
&=P(W^{-1}\leq 0.198^{-1})-(1-0.975)\tag{0}\\
&=P(W^{-1}\leq 5.05)-0.025\\
&=0.975-0.025=0.95
\end{align}
$$
where in (0) we used the fact that $W\geq 0.198\iff W^{-1}\leq 0.198^{-1}$.